# saving form data in html

Tags: html, css, web

I only know CSS and HTML. I have to create a web page with an account opening form. My faculty had told me to make it at that so I built it. He asked me not to host it.

Now he is asking me to take everyone response and create a database. I could do that by sending the webpage to everyone and asking them to download the page locally in their system and then open and fill the form. But I do not know how to save that data. If I could get the output in a text file it will be time saving, but even if the page retains the information while my classmates send it back to me it will be great. Can anyone help me on how to save the data?

I know creating a word file would have been much easier but he wanted web page so I am stuck.

Comment: No way to save the data? I have the whole form ready.

Comment: Then you must have database hosted on server to access it globally

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with only HTML and CSS. To do this, you would have to [code a server-sided page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) so that you can serve HTML pages to your users, as well as receive data back from them.

Comment: Can I have a JavaScript that saves information on the page. I can create a dummy submit button . My classmates can then return the pages back.

Comment: You can use Javascript to send the form's information to a server, but you will still need to write some server-side code to receive and process (submit to a database) said information.